# How to check another button while action performed

Tags: java

I have 2 buttons, when first button is clicked, it runs an infinite loop and I want it to stop when i click the second button.
What is the proper way to do this since I'm new on using java.

I know this wrong but I just want to make clear what I'm trying to do

```
private void button1_buttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    while( !button2.isClicked() ) {} }
```

*edited*

here's what i have try

```
boolean sthap = false;
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

   while(!sthap){
   System.out.println("run");
   }
}                                        

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    sthap=true;
}
```

still. It stucks on the loop

*edited2*

```
boolean sthap = false;
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

   runrun();
   }


private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    sthap=true;
}       

public void runrun(){
while(!sthap){
   System.out.println("run");}
}
```

it still stuck

Comment: Use a variable as flag.

Comment: I have think about that but still having problem on the implementation
'int a=0;'
'private void button1_buttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {'
while (a==0)  {} }'

'private void button2_buttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {'
a=1;)  {} }'

Comment: If you start an infinite loop on the event thread, you won't be able to handle the second button press since the event thread is busy.

Comment: do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Do while loop in another thread.

Comment: @aninaisyah Obviously you intend to do something besides just running an empty loop. What is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
boolean sthap = false;

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!sthap) {
                System.out.println("run");
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    sthap = true;
}
```

Comment: error show:


"lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.7
(use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)

lambda expression not expected here.

not suitable constructor found for Thread(<none>)
constructor Thread.Thread(Runnable) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; <none> cannot be converted to Runnable)
constructor Thread.Thread(String) is not applicable
(argument mismatch;<none> cannot be converted to String)
----"

Comment: I changed my answer for java7.

Comment: I try for new project, and it's works! thanks for your help ^_^/

Answer (score 2):

define a flag variable like;

```
boolean isBUttonClicked = false;
```

and in your `while loop`

use if statement like

```
while(true){
   if(isButtonClicked){
     isButtonClicked = false;
     break;
   }else{
      //do your job
   }
}
```

in the second button `action performed method`

use isButtonClicked and make it true like

```
isButtonClicked = true;
```

Comment: Just above the break statement make the `isButtonClicked` value to `false` so next time the logic will run when the button1 is clicked.

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam you are right, I forget it. I'm editing right now. Thanks !

Comment: Since the "while" loop is on the action void of a first button, it did not response anything about the second button. I've try to print something at the second button void, it did not show if i already clicked the first button.

Comment: @aninaisyah if you know SwingWorkers we can do something about it or you can use Som Bhattacharyya answer.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a static variable like this `boolean flag=false`  outside the button methods.
Then inside button 1,

`private void button1_buttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
 while( !flag ) {} }`

and inside button2,

`private void button1_buttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
 flag = true}`

Comment: Doing like this the flag will be always `false` after button2 is clicked also double check the methods both are same.